# Selecting all the Document Types in umbraco

Tags: list, razor, umbraco

I am using umbraco 7 and have been trying to figure out how to select an array of the distinct document types of a given node's children.  I can't hardcode this because I will be needing many different kinds of document types so I was hoping to do a distinct select of them but I can't seem to get my code correct, maybe there is no "distinct" select or maybe I can't just get individual alias strings from the methods I have tried?

Has anyone else attempted this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance of interface type `IPublishedContent`, you should be able to get the distinct document types of all children as follows:

```
node.Children.Select(c => c.DocumentTypeAlias).Distinct()
```

Comment: So, this whole time the closest I got was when I had added a parenthesis after the call to Children.  Thank you.